# Microsoft bot builder deep linking

Tags: skype, botframework, slack

Can we do deep linking for Skype or Slack with the [Microsoft Bot Framework](https://dev.botframework.com/)?
Specifically, I need a link that would allow me to pass custom parameters to my bot at the time of invocation, as we can do for Telegram such as https://telegram.me/UniversalAgent1Bot?start=30|1

Comment: As there is no any start button in slack, you cannot pass any parameter in start point!

Comment: The "?start=30|1" parameter above is just an example - in Facebook messenger that becomes "?ref=30|1". Do Skype or Slack have anything similar?

Comment: I know your example, but in telegram just you can send a parameter for start and no more! As, there is no start point for Skype and Slack, you can't send any parameter to detect specific entry!

Comment: Thanks for that. Is there no way to achieve the same with a custom message then? such as when you click on the url, it starts the slack/skype bot and sends the message specified in the URL to them? I have already tried Skype URI's but noted that they don't work with bots - or I could not get them right...

Comment: As you can't start the bot with Url in Skype/Slack, you can't send any custom message to start the bot with an specific value in the Url. You might offer it in their developer community.

Comment: Just FYI, using Slack outside of the MS bot framework, I use the following link to have `token` sent back to me when the user clicks the link: `<a href="https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?scope=commands,bot&client_id={{app_id}}&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com%2Fslack%2Fwebhook&state={{token}}.{{z}}" target="_blank">`

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.skype.com/en/developer/create-addbot-button/ for details on how to create a button to add a bot to contacts on web.

If you want to create a deep link for iOS or Android, you can use this URI:

skype:28:bot-id-guid-value?chat

For example, skype:28:12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012?chat

But to my knowledge, you cannot add custom parameters to these URLs. More details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745882.aspx